# aap name on icon similar to app name in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I have app name on my app icon in iphone
Will it cause rejection from app stor
Please guide as I developed my first iphone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the app name on your app icon.
No, it will not cause rejection.
Next time, do some reading http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html and the answer above's

Comment: I guess but it's not my call. The company I work for has made plenty apps with text on the icons and it's usually the client the one who choses this version.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that would create any issue.. make sure your app icon meets requirement here. [Icons and Sizes for iPhone and iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)